# if i select 1 first, then user change item selected why it won't change corresponding picker?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, picker

if user picks 2 first then it's ok to change item selected to 1, but if 1 gets selected it wont change the corresponding number of pickers to show 2 pickers, why wont it change?

```
 void ItemSelected(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    //to get value user selected
    //var drainx = drain.Items[drain.SelectedIndex];
    //DisplayAlert(drainx, "selected Value", "OK");

    string drainxy = drain.Items[drain.SelectedIndex]; 


    switch (drainxy)
    {
    case "1":
    DisplayAlert(drainxy, "selected Value", "OK");
    drainPicker1();
    drain2Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
    break;
    case "2":
    DisplayAlert(drainxy, "selected Value", "OK");
    drainPicker1();
    drainPicker2();
    drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
    break;
    }
 }
```

"regarding drain and picker"

```
<Picker x:Name="drain" Title="Drain #" 
Margin="190,-30,50,0" TextColor="{StaticResource pinkColor}"
SelectedIndexChanged="ItemSelected"/>  

<Picker x:Name="drain1Picker" Title="Drain 1 Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drain2Picker" Title="Drain 2 Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drain3Picker" Title="Drain 3 Location" />
<Picker x:Name="drain4Picker" Title="Drain 4 Location" />
```

Comment: Could you please post the code regarding the `drain` and the `drainPicker`-s?

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (drainxy)
    {
    case "1":
    DisplayAlert(drainxy, "selected Value", "OK");
    drainPicker1();
    drain2Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
    break;
    case "2":
    DisplayAlert(drainxy, "selected Value", "OK");
    drainPicker1.IsVisible = true;
    drainPicker2.IsVisible = true;
    drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
    drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
    break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much.... so calling the function in the class doesn't work because i wasn't actually accessing the picker in xaml, it's not the picker ...  the function or method i'm calling is the wrong step....